# "exit status 1" error when invoking "useInterrupt" method

Tags: interrupt, arduino-leonardo, adafruit, audio, compilation-errors

for context to this post you can catch up on [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55466/stacking-3-of-the-same-shields-on-top-of-each-other-and-instructing-them-in-sync)

I am working with an Arduino Leonardo and Adafruit Music Maker shield.

I am trying to use the `startPlayingFile` method via the interrupt pin but I am getting a `exit status 1` error when instantiating the interrupt pin. I have pin pointed the error down this one statement. If I comment this statement out, the sketch compiles.

```
if (! musicPlayer1.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_PIN_INT))
    Serial.println(F("DREQ pin is not an interrupt pin"));
```

The frustrating thing is that this is also the case with the example sketch "player_interrupts" provided by Adafruit.

Does anyone have a clue as to what is causing this compile error?

---

Here's my code which is a slightly simplified version of the example sketch

```
// include SPI, MP3 and SD libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_VS1053.h>
#include <SD.h>

// These are the pins used for the breakout example
#define BREAKOUT_RESET  9      // VS1053 reset pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_CS     10     // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_DCS    8      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)

// These are the pins used for the music maker shield
//SHIELD 1
#define SHIELD_RESET  -1      // VS1053 reset pin (unused!)
#define SHIELD_CS     7      // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS    6      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
#define DREQ          3       // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin


// SHIELD 2
#define SHIELD_CS_2     5      // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS_2    2      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
#define DREQ_2          0       // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin

// These are common pins between breakout and shield
#define CARDCS 4     // Card chip select pin
// DREQ should be an Int pin, see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt

  Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer1 = Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS, SHIELD_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);
  Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer2 = Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS_2, SHIELD_DCS_2, DREQ_2, CARDCS);
//  Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer3 = Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS_3, SHIELD_DCS_3, DREQ_3, CARDCS);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (! musicPlayer1.begin()) { // initialise the music player
     Serial.println(F("Couldn't find VS1053_1, do you have the right pins defined?"));
     while (1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("VS1053 found"));

  musicPlayer1.sineTest(0x44, 500);    // Make a tone to indicate VS1053 is working
  musicPlayer2.sineTest(0x44, 500);    

  if (!SD.begin(CARDCS)) {
    Serial.println(F("SD failed, or not present"));
    while (1);  // don't do anything more
  }
  Serial.println("SD OK!");

  // list files
  printDirectory(SD.open("/"), 0);

  // Set volume for left, right channels. lower numbers == louder volume!
  musicPlayer1.setVolume(20,20);
  musicPlayer2.setVolume(20,20);

  /***** Two interrupt options! *******/ 
  // This option uses timer0, this means timer1 & t2 are not required
  // (so you can use 'em for Servos, etc) BUT millis() can lose time
  // since we're hitchhiking on top of the millis() tracker
  //musicPlayer.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_TIMER0_INT);

  // This option uses a pin interrupt. No timers required! But DREQ
  // must be on an interrupt pin. For Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimilla
  // that's Digital #2 or #3
  // See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt for other pins
  // *** This method is preferred
  if (! musicPlayer1.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_PIN_INT))
    Serial.println(F("DREQ pin is not an interrupt pin"));

//     if (! musicPlayer2.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_PIN_INT))
//    Serial.println(F("DREQ pin is not an interrupt pin"));
}


void loop() {  
  // Alternately, we can just play an entire file at once
  // This doesn't happen in the background, instead, the entire
  // file is played and the program will continue when it's done!
//  musicPlayer1.playFullFile("track001.mp3");

  // INTERRUPT
  // StartS playing a file, then we can do stuff while waiting for it to finish
  musicPlayer1.startPlayingFile("track002.mp3");
//  musicPlayer2.startPlayingFile("track002.mp3");


}


/// File listing helper
void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
   while(true) {

     File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
     if (! entry) {
       // no more files
       //Serial.println("**nomorefiles**");
       break;
     }
     for (uint8_t i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
       Serial.print('\t');
     }
     Serial.print(entry.name());
     if (entry.isDirectory()) {
       Serial.println("/");
       printDirectory(entry, numTabs+1);
     } else {
       // files have sizes, directories do not
       Serial.print("\t\t");
       Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
     }
     entry.close();
   }
}
```

---

This is the output of the compiler which seems to show the error happening at "Linking everything together..."

```
Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows Store 1.8.15.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries -libraries C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:leonardo -ide-version=10807 -build-path C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_535084 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\Test_simul_play\Test_simul_play.ino
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries -libraries C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:leonardo -ide-version=10807 -build-path C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_535084 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\Test_simul_play\Test_simul_play.ino
Using board 'leonardo' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o nul
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\libraries\\SPI\\src" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o nul
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\libraries\\SPI\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\edwar\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Adafruit_VS1053" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o nul
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\libraries\\SPI\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\edwar\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Adafruit_VS1053" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\libraries\\SD\\src" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o nul
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src\SPI.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_VS1053\Adafruit_VS1053.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD\src\File.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD\src\SD.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD\src\utility\Sd2Card.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD\src\utility\SdFile.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD\src\utility\SdVolume.cpp
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\libraries\\SPI\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\edwar\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Adafruit_VS1053" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\libraries\\SD\\src" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 "-DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Unknown\"" "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Leonardo\"" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\leonardo" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\libraries\\SPI\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\edwar\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\Adafruit_VS1053" "-IC:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\libraries\\SD\\src" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling library "SPI"
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp.o
Compiling library "Adafruit_VS1053"
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\Adafruit_VS1053\Adafruit_VS1053.cpp.o
Compiling library "SD"
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SD\File.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SD\SD.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SD\utility\Sd2Card.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SD\utility\SdVolume.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_927460\libraries\SD\utility\SdFile.cpp.o
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_535084\core\core_arduino_avr_leonardo_83dd9225a3a2a4e5654b35f3e742d65a.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega32u4 -o "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460/Test_simul_play.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\sketch\\Test_simul_play.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SPI\\SPI.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\Adafruit_VS1053\\Adafruit_VS1053.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SD\\File.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SD\\SD.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SD\\utility\\Sd2Card.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SD\\utility\\SdFile.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460\\libraries\\SD\\utility\\SdVolume.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460/..\\arduino_cache_535084\\core\\core_arduino_avr_leonardo_83dd9225a3a2a4e5654b35f3e742d65a.a" "-LC:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_927460" -lm
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src\SPI.cpp: In function 'begin':

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI\src\SPI.cpp:64:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

 }

 ^

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.

lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc returned 1 exit status

compilation terminated.

c:/program files/windowsapps/arduinollc.arduinoide_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: error: lto-wrapper failed

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI 
Using library Adafruit_VS1053 at version 1.0.5 in folder: C:\Users\edwar\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_VS1053 
Using library SD at version 1.2.2 in folder: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\SD 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Leonardo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is OK. It compiles in [IDE 1.8.6](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). You have some strange version of IDE and the compiler crashes with "internal compiler error: Segmentation fault"

Comment: Looks like the windows app store version. Buggy as hell, don't touch it. Same as all things Windows really...